# How to handle local storage missing item in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, storage, local

I have a function that saves some values in the local storage. In another method, the values are reloaded from the local storage. What is the best way to handle the missing item from the local storage? If the user deletes it from the local storage or if it simply is inexistent.
The methods which get and set the local storage coordinates:

```
    get savedValues(): { val1: number, val2: number, val3: number }[] {
        if (localStorage.getItem('savedValues') === null) {
            console.log("null");
            return null;
        }
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedValues'));
    }

    set savedValues(value: { val1: number, val2: number, val3: number }[]) {
        localStorage.setItem('savedValues', JSON.stringify(value));
    }
```

The method where the coordinates are reloaded from the local storage:

```
    reload(): void {
        try {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.savedValues.length; i++) {
                this.oldValues[i].val1 = this.savedValues[i].val1;
                this.oldValues[i].val2 = this.savedValues[i].val2;
                this.oldValues[i].val3 = this.savedValues[i].val3;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            console.log("savedValuesitem is null in the local storage");
        }
    }
```

What is the proper way to try catch the exception of the null field from the local storage? I also tried

```
if (this.savedValues!== null) {...}
```

But this seems to take forever to check in the local storage.

Answer (score 0):

try to check on undefinied:

```
if (this.savedCoordinates !== undefined) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use try/catch for this, because not having a value in the local storage isn't really an error but just a normal/possible behavior. I'd do it with a simple null-check:

```
reload(): void {
    if (this.savedCoordinates !== null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.savedCoordinates.length; i++) {
            this.nodes[i].x = this.savedCoordinates[i].x;
            this.nodes[i].y = this.savedCoordinates[i].y;
        }
        return;
    }

    console.log("savedCoordinates item is null in the local storage");
    return;
}
```

Comment: @OP: In addition, I just realized that you use Angular - `get/set` will run with its change detection and thus very often - this might be the reason for it taking so long.
I'd recommend simply using basic functions (`getCoordinates` and `getCoordinates`) to set and get the values (which will only run when you call them).

Answer (score 0):

you should check the localStorage only once:

```
    reload(): void {
   
        let coordinates=this.savedCoordinates;
        if (coordinates == null) {
         ...
        }
        else{
         for (var i = 0; i < coordinates; i++) {
            this.nodes[i].x = coordinates[i].x;
            this.nodes[i].y = coordinates[i].y;
           }
         }
   
   }
```